# How to split text into three columns without breaking words

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I want to split text field into three columns without breaking the words in following way:

Column1 (0-50 characters, without breaking the words)
Column2 (51-100 characters, without breaking the words)
Column3 (101-350 characters, without breaking the words)

#### Example text

> Entering from the hydraulic swim platform aft up the starboard side
> stairway you enter the aft deck with aft seating, teak dining table,
> and crew quarters entry hatch to port. Forward to starboard are stairs
> leading up to the flybridge and to port forward you enter the triple
> pane sliding glass door to the galley and main salon.

#### Result

Column1 = 'Entering from the hydraulic swim platform aft up'
Column2 = 'the starboard side stairway you enter the aft deck'
Column3 = 'with aft seating, teak dining table, and crew quarters entry hatch to port. Forward to starboard are stairs leading up to the flybridge and to port forward you enter the triple pane sliding glass door to the galley and main salon.'

I am using following code, but it's not generating the results properly. For example, in the below code the word 'deck' appears in the second and third columns.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

```sql
DECLARE @InputText varchar(350)
SET @InputText=RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(
'Entering from the hydraulic swim platform aft up the starboard side stairway you enter the aft deck with aft seating, teak dining table, and crew quarters entry hatch to port. Forward to starboard are stairs leading up to the flybridge and to port forward you enter the triple pane sliding glass door to the galley and main salon.'
,350)))

--removing double spaces
while charindex('  ',@InputText)>0 begin 
    set @InputText=REPLACE(@InputText,'  ',' ');
end

DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Id int identity(1,1), 
    ColText varchar(max)
)

INSERT @T 
select 
value as Text
from STRING_SPLIT(@InputText,' ')

---------------------------------------------------------------------
--COLUMN 1 varchar(50)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @Col1 varchar(50)
SET @Col1=''

DECLARE @Counter int
SET @Counter=0

DECLARE @InputLength int
SET @InputLength=0

WHILE LEN(@Col1)<50
BEGIN   
    SET @Counter=@Counter+1
    SET @InputLength=LEN(@Col1)+(SELECT LEN(ColText) FROM @T WHERE Id=@Counter) + 1
            
    IF @InputLength>50
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT ColText FROM @T WHERE Id=@Counter) IS NULL
            BREAK
        ELSE
            SET @Col1=@Col1+(SELECT ColText FROM @T WHERE Id=@Counter)+' '                      
    END
END

---------------------------------------------------------------------
--COLUMN 2 varchar(50)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @Col2 varchar(50)
SET @Col2=''

SET @Counter=@Counter-1

SET @InputLength=0

WHILE LEN(@Col2)<50
BEGIN   
    SET @Counter=@Counter+1
    SET @InputLength=LEN(@Col2)+(SELECT LEN(ColText) FROM @T WHERE Id=@Counter) + 1
    
    IF @InputLength>50
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT ColText FROM @T WHERE Id=@Counter) IS NULL
            BREAK
        ELSE
            SET @Col2=@Col2+(SELECT ColText FROM @T WHERE Id=@Counter)+' '              
    END
END

---------------------------------------------------------------------
--COLUMN 3 varchar(250)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @Col3 varchar(250)
SET @Col3=''

SET @Counter=@Counter-1

SET @InputLength=0

WHILE LEN(@Col3)<250
BEGIN   
    SET @Counter=@Counter+1
    SET @InputLength=LEN(@Col3)+(SELECT LEN(ColText) FROM @T WHERE Id=@Counter) + 1
    
    IF @InputLength>250
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT ColText FROM @T WHERE Id=@Counter) IS NULL
            BREAK
        ELSE
            SET @Col3=@Col3+(SELECT ColText FROM @T WHERE Id=@Counter)+' '          
    END
END

---------------------------------------------------------------------
--Final result
---------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT 
ISNULL(@Col1,'') AS Col1_Value,
ISNULL(@Col2,'') AS Col2_Value, 
ISNULL(@Col3,'') AS Col3_Value
```

Comment: It may help to clarify. Is column one characters 0-50, column 2 characters 51-100, and column 3 characters 101-350 (whilst not breaking words)?

Comment: Column one 0-50, column two 51-100, column three 101-350